# Member function to return sum of column in another object

Tags: arrays, object, plsql, sqlplus

I currently have implemented the code below in oracle.

I am struggling on creating a member function to return the number of residents in a village.

How would I go about doing this and ultimately create an anonymous block to test and then finally running a select statement against it?

**house object**

```
create or replace type house as object (
 house_no number,
 postcode varchar2(10),
 no_of_residents number,
 member function pass(h house) return number
);
/
```

**house object body**

```
create or replace type body houses_p12214840 as
member function pass(h houses_p12214840) return number is
begin
    if (h.house_no=house_no) and (h.road_name=road_name) 
        and (h.postcode=postcode)
        and (h.no_of_residents=no_of_residents) 
        then 
            return 1;
        else 
            return 0;
    end if;
end;
end;
/
```

**village array type, holding multiple houses**

```
create or replace type village_array is varray(50) of house;
/
```

**my village table**

```
create table village (
 villageid number,
 village_name varchar2(25),
 village village_array,
 PRIMARY KEY (villageid)
);
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Not absolutely clear about your desired result(s).

If you only need the sum of all residents in each village you don't need a member function (neither a "bool" [1/0]).

Use the `SUM` function instead in a Column-Inline-Query:

```
SELECT T.VILLAGEID,
       T.VILLAGE_NAME,
       (SELECT SUM(T2.NO_OF_RESIDENTS)
        FROM   TABLE(T.HOUSES) T2) SUM_RESIDENTS
FROM   VILLAGE T;
```

I used following example with some changes:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
CLEAR;


CREATE TYPE HOUSE AS OBJECT
(
  HOUSE_NO        NUMBER,
  ROAD_NAME       VARCHAR2(255),
  POSTCODE        VARCHAR2(10),
  NO_OF_RESIDENTS NUMBER,
  MEMBER FUNCTION PASS(H HOUSE) RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY HOUSE AS
  MEMBER FUNCTION PASS(H HOUSE) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    IF (H.HOUSE_NO = HOUSE_NO) AND (H.ROAD_NAME = ROAD_NAME) AND (H.POSTCODE = POSTCODE) AND (H.NO_OF_RESIDENTS = NO_OF_RESIDENTS) THEN
      RETURN 1;
    ELSE
      RETURN 0;
    END IF;
  END;
END;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE HOUSES_ARRAY IS VARRAY(50) OF HOUSE;
/

CREATE TABLE VILLAGE (
 VILLAGEID    NUMBER,
 VILLAGE_NAME VARCHAR2(25),
 HOUSES      HOUSES_ARRAY,
 PRIMARY KEY (VILLAGEID)
);


INSERT INTO village(VILLAGEID,VILLAGE_NAME,HOUSES) VALUES (1,'Village_1',HOUSES_ARRAY(HOUSE(1,'Road_1',12000,10),HOUSE(2,'Road_1',12000,2)));
INSERT INTO village(VILLAGEID,VILLAGE_NAME,HOUSES) VALUES (2,'Village_2',HOUSES_ARRAY(HOUSE(1,'Road_2',12010,5),HOUSE(2,'Road_2',12010,20)));


SELECT T.VILLAGEID,
       T.VILLAGE_NAME,
       (SELECT SUM(T2.NO_OF_RESIDENTS)
        FROM   TABLE(T.HOUSES) T2) SUM_RESIDENTS
FROM   VILLAGE T;


ROLLBACK;

DROP TABLE VILLAGE;
DROP TYPE HOUSES_ARRAY;
DROP TYPE HOUSE;
```

Output:

```
 VILLAGEID VILLAGE_NAME              SUM_RESIDENTS
---------- ------------------------- -------------
         1 Village_1                            12
         2 Village_2                            25

SQL>
```

or

```
SELECT T.VILLAGEID,
       T.VILLAGE_NAME,
       SUM(T2.NO_OF_RESIDENTS) SUM_RESIDENTS
FROM   VILLAGE T,
       TABLE(T.HOUSES) T2
GROUP  BY T.VILLAGEID,
          T.VILLAGE_NAME
;
```

Be careful of too many context changes (SQL<->PLSQL).
If you can do it with SQL, do it with SQL.